# Second quantization of Klein Gordon field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, klein-gordon-equation, second-quantization

Does the second quantization of the Klein Gordon field which involves using the harmonic oscillator paradigm ultimately lead to the conclusion that electromagnetic field is nothing but photons(bosons) trapped in a box oscillating simple harmonically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field excitations $a_k(t)=a(\vec k,t)$ are quantum harmonic oscillators. As you see, these fields/operators do not depend on $\vec x$. So there is not "trapped in a (spatial coordinate $\vec x$) box".

Moreover, if one is interested with some target space (the space of "$a_k,a^\dagger_k"$) , that is the space of $X_k$, wich $X_k(t) \approx a_k(t)+a^\dagger_k(t)$, there is no limitation too, because the energy operator $ E = a^\dagger_k a_k + 1/2$ may take any value $N\omega_k + 1/2$ (with $\omega_k = \sqrt{k^2+m^2}$, for a state with $N$ photons of momentum $\vec k$. And you will have an equivalent conclusion, if you look at the operator $X_k^2(t)$. This operator is not bounded too, so there is no "trapped in the box" for the target space $X_k$, too.

[EDIT]
Precisions due to O.P. comments :

As an example of a one-particle boson state, you may take, $|k\rangle = a^\dagger(\vec k)|0\rangle$ (the relation with the previous $a^\dagger(\vec k,t)$ is $a^\dagger(\vec k,t) = a^\dagger(\vec k) e^{i\omega_kt}$). Here $|0\rangle$ is the vacuum, the state of minimum energy. This one-particle boson state has a precise momentum/energy $k$, and by virtue of quantum mechanicals principles, spread among all space-time. So, this represents one bosonic particle of momentum/energy $k$.  However, you are always free to build a wave-packet one-particle state by superposition $|w\rangle = \sum\limits_k~ a_k |k\rangle$. This is a one-particle state too, but this is no more an eigenstate for momentum/energy (so you cannot say that this state has a precise momentum/energy), and it could be localized in space-time.

Comment: I understand. So, the quantized entities of the Klein-Gordon field are just dirac delta spikes or are they photons/bosons?

Comment: @TorstenHĕrculĕCärlemän : I updated the answser